# Uglify css classname like instagram or facebook

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can i uglifiy my css files like on instagram or facebook?

e.g `_8f735`, _`oofbn`, `_6ltyr`
It's some react plugins or something? I saw this only on instagram and facebook.

Comment: Do you know how to use GuntJS? Or GulpJS? Also Uglify just means to concat and minify your files which you should do for production.

Comment: but im asking about this one, i want classname exactly like in fb or insta

Comment: Thats fine GruntJS or GulpJS will still accomplish that and neither are hard to use or learn. But like I said before all they are doing is minifying the file which is what Uglify means.  GruntJS has a cssmin that will do what your asking. Do you want a code sample?

Comment: Also if you're looking for the naming conventions that they are using like _oofbn then your not going to find anything to do that for you. You can create a simple task to run in deployment with Grunt or Gulp that will go through and change your css but there is really no need for that.

Comment: i want compress and uglify my css files and synchronous this between js files and html
e.g in js i add css class with name "active" and then i want compress this inside my js file, css, and html

Comment: Im not sure I am following. Are you wanting to compress and uglify your css into one file? And then in a seperate file compress and uglify your JS?

Comment: `button.onclick = function() { this.classList.add('active'); }` and my css file:
`.active { background: red; }`
I want output something like:
`button.onclick = function() { this.classList.add('_oofbn'); }` and in css file `._oofbn { background: red; }`

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so? You can still accomplish this by creating a custom task that will go through and change all class names and all correlating names in other files. This would be very tedious and painful to accomplish almost nothing.

Comment: the same purpose like for facebook - performance... Its just for production i dont want this on dev... No words...

Comment: I understand compressing and uglifying for performance and you can accomplish that with the use of grunt fairly easily. Changing the name off css from active to _oofbn is not going to change your performance.

Comment: Or you could just ensure that your web server has gzip compression enabled and be done with it.

Comment: @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794232/minify-mangle-css-classnames-in-jsx-and-css-output-from-webpack-or-other-progra

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

Example from [React CSS Modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules):

> In the context of React, CSS Modules look like this:
>
> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import styles from './table.css';
>
> export default class Table extends React.Component {
>     render () {
>         return <div className={styles.table}>
>             <div className={styles.row}>
>                 <div className={styles.cell}>A0</div>
>                 <div className={styles.cell}>B0</div>
>             </div>
>         </div>;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Rendering the component will produce a markup similar to:
>
> ```
> <div class="table__table___32osj">
>     <div class="table__row___2w27N">
>         <div class="table__cell___2w27N">A0</div>
>         <div class="table__cell___1oVw5">B0</div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> and a corresponding CSS file that matches those CSS classes.

**Important:** class names can have different format.

Answer (score 1):

What you want, is probably done by using classname maps.

Currently, you have different options with the class rename already implemented:

- [Birdy](https://github.com/iiegor/birdy), a Node.js web server that is using the behavior that you want for production.
- [react-spa-boilerplate](https://github.com/iiegor/react-spa-boilerplate), a react boilerplate for building single page apps that uses class renaming.

If you are searching for a library to do this by yourself, see one of these:

- closure-stylesheets
- postcss
- webpack & css-loader

Probably there are some other alternatives out there but for me these are the best ones.

Anyway, keep in mind that in the most cases, this is a unnecessary step that only should be done for pages with a very high network traffic to reduce the bytes sent to the client.