# Minify/Mangle CSS Classnames in JSX and CSS output from Webpack (or other programmatic means)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, postcss

I'd like to minify my classnames (for very minimal source protection purposes) in both my output CSS files and in the rendered JSX from my React components similarly to this Webpack plugin: https://github.com/vreshch/optimize-css-classnames-plugin

Is there any existing option I can use to achieve this, either Webpack or otherwise? Thanks very much.

**From:**

```
<div className="long-class-name"></div>

.long-class-name {
 }
```

**To:**

```
<div class="a"></div>
.a {
}
```

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reducing-css-bundle-size-70-by-cutting-the-class-names-and-using-scope-isolation-625440de600b

Comment: Plagin mini-css-class-name: https://github.com/shoonia/mini-css-class-name

Comment: How can we achieve this functionality with create-react-app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you're already using Webpack, I think one good option is to use [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) to accomplish that. You can use either [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules) or [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) to do that, for example.

Basically, by using CSS Modules, you can `import` your CSS and treat it as a JSON. So, if you write `.long-class-name { }` you'll have something like this `{ 'long-class-name': '<<interpolated name>>' }`. The trick here is that the `<<interpolated name>>` in my example is something you can set programmaticaly.

Webpack has some predefined tokens that you can use, as you can see here: https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils#interpolatename. And you can check an example here:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if you want something more "customized", you can specify a `getLocalIdent` function:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
        getLocalIdent: (context, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
          return 'whatever_random_class_name';
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please, refer to the [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules) to read more about the options on `CSS Modules`.

Doing this way, you can specify your class names the way you need and solve your problem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey @Slbox, did it help you?

Comment: I didn't end up pursuing this, but this answer should theoretically work.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone wanting to easily mangle classnames in Next.js, use [my package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-optimized-classnames)!